# Pie is not a function in Ember D3 Pie Chart

Tags: d3.js, ember.js

I am currently struggling to create a pie chart in Ember using D3 as installed by the add-on [ember-d3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-d3). To create the chart I am working backwords from a great example posted on git [here](https://github.com/pbishop16/ember-d3-sample3).

With my current code I receiving an error in the console that 'pie' is not a function. The code is as follows:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Component from 'ember-component';
import {arc, pie} from 'd3-shape';
import { select } from 'd3-selection';
import { scaleOrdinal } from 'd3-scale';


export default Component.extend({

  radius() {
    let width = this.get('width'),
        height = this.get('height');

    return Math.min(width, height) / 2;
  },
  color() {
    return scaleOrdinal().range(['#A60F2B', '#648C85', '#B3F2C9', '#528C18', '#C3F25C'])
  },
  arc() {
    let radius = this.radius();
    return arc().outerRadius(radius - 10).innerRadius(0);
  },
  labelArc() {
    let radius = this.radius();
    return arc().outerRadius(radius - 40).innerRadius(radius - 40);
  },

  didInsertElement() {
    let data = this.get('data');
    this.pieChart(data);
  },

  pieChart(dataIn, dataIndexIn) {
    let width = this.get('width'),
        height = this.get('height'),
        arc = this.arc(),
        labelArc = this.labelArc(),
        color = this.color(),
        that = this;

    let data = dataIn;

    let pie = pie()
          .value(function(d) { return d.count; })(data[dataIndexIn]);

    let svg = select("#pie-chart")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + ", " + height/2 + ")");

    let g = svg.selectAll("arc")
          .data(pie)
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "arc");

    g.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
        .style("stroke", "#222")
        .each(function(d) { this._current = d; that.set('chartContext', this._current); });

    //Labels
    g.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.data.color; })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("fill", "#FFF")
        .each(function(d) { this._current = d; that.set('chartContextLable', this._current); });

  },

});
```

As far as I can tell d3-shape is being imported correctly as I do not receive an error about 'arc'. If I do remove 'arc' from the import statement I receive an error to say that 'arc' is not defined. This suggests the module is importing correctly.

The shape module also imports correctly on other component charts that do not use the pie function.

I think this suggests a syntax error but I can't see one.

Mock data is passed to the component via the controller and template helper:

```
data: [
  { label: 'Abulia', count: 10 },
  { label: 'Betelgeuse', count: 20 },
  { label: 'Cantaloupe', count: 30 },
  { label: 'Dijkstra', count: 40 }
],

{{pie-chart-example data=data dataIndex=dataIndex}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't declare variables with the same name as the imports

working version: https://ember-twiddle.com/a658207aa8800816329f95b4e1b4860f?openFiles=components.pie-chart.js%2Ctemplates.components.pie-chart.hbs

creating functions that don't do much also makes the code harder to understand which in turn causes more problems.

Comment: I figured this out yesterday and this was super correct. Thank you very much for taking the time to reply and create the twiddle.Frankly I was a bit embarrassed about it!

Comment: happy to help, the error message should be more descriptive like "arc has already been declared" the problem is the way that the transpiler work

Comment: Still running into this two years later! I'm surprised webpack isn't smart enough to just rename the variables...

Comment: Hi, I know this question is already closed but I am still having this error. Which version of D3 are you using?